# Unable to push into heroku master-rake aborted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have put my code on `github` but when i push to `heroku`

**Error:-**

```
rake aborted!
   couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
   (in /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/app/assets/javascript
s/application.js:15)
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in`process_requi
re_directive'
/tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in  process_directives'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) i
n define'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_84917108-19fa-4e88-8644-70f8ceccdb4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2   levels) i
n define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:sheltered-ravine-2545.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sheltered-ravine-2545.git'`
```

When i add a `gem twitter-bootstrap-rails` it shows different error as i am working on `windows` where `sass` in unable to load.

**my gem-file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'protected_attributes'


gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "devise", "~> 3.2.2"
gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.7"



gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'


gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

In my **applicaition.js**

```
 // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
 // listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post your application.js file?

Comment: i have added `application.js`.i have my code on git.

Comment: i think i should remove `//=twitter/bootstrap`.?

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.js` file requires a file called `bootstrap.js` in a folder called `twitter` with this line:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

So, add the needed file, `bootstrap.js` to `vendor/assets/javascripts/twitter/`

---

Or, if you don't want that file as part of your application, just remove that line that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

After running bundle install did you run the generator?

`rails generate bootstrap:install static`

Comment: Those are the instructions for installing the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem from the official website (http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/) Place the gem in your gemfile, run bundle install and then run the generator.